# How is the "Interesting" tab populated?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

When I load up [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) the **Interesting** tab is selected by default.

I'm not complaining, because they are all, by and large, very interesting but many of these questions have either no answers, no upvotes or both, so I am interested to know how you define interesting? Is this automated or are questions marked as Interesting by experienced moderators? If it is automated, what properties does a question needs to have to be classed as Interesting?

Comment: By some hidden algorithm. One thing for sure is that edited questions are bumped.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/ I should note, however, that the interesting tab appears only on SO.

Comment: @waiwai933 So it does, my mistake, I have amended the question...and regardless your link contains the answer so thank you!

Comment: @waiwai933 Post that as an answer, since well... it is.

Comment: @AnnaLear It's also a link-only answer; the rest of my comment, was, in fact, a comment.

Answer (score 9):

as @waiwai933 has already found the answer, this question should not remain unanswered. Here is a formatted abstract from [the relevant blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/).

> Here’s how it works. Starting with a list of the last 3,000 active
> questions:
>
> - drop questions containing any of your ignored tags
> - drop closed questions if you lack the reputation required to vote for reopening
> - drop questions scoring -4 or lower
>
> Next, apply the following score formula to the remaining questions:
>
> - your [interesting tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/expressing-your-tag-preferences/)         +1,500 per interesting tag, up to +2,000 total
> - your top 40 scoring tags   maximum of +1,000 per tag (scaled), up to +2,000 total
> - question score                  +200 × score, up to +1,000 total
> - total answer score             -200 × score, up to -1,000 total
> - number of answers             -200 × answers, up to -1,000 total
> - number of views                -15 × views, up to -1,000 total
> - question last activity date  -1 × (seconds / 15)
>
> Count it all up and take the top 90 by score.
>
> We also mix in a few random questions from the last 3,000 — 10% (9)
> for logged in users and 20% (18) for anonymous users.