# How does Stack Overflow determine whether a question is an interesting one?

Tags: support, homepage

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16636118/240613) half an hour ago. It never appeared on the home page in "interesting" tab.

Why? What makes it uninteresting for Stack Overflow engine? How does it determine whether a question is worth being shown on the home page?

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148911/how-is-the-interesting-tab-populated

Comment: Only 3 views after 36 minutes. If you wait longer, you should get [a badge](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/63/tumbleweed) for it. Oh, [you already have one](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/63/tumbleweed?userid=240613).

Comment: The tooltip for the tab answers your question: questions that may be of interest to you based on your history and tag preference.