# Which questions are highlighted in the question list?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

As seen in the following image, some questions have background colors and others do not.
What's the criteria for the selection?

[image]

What does the interesting tab mean?
I thought it means viewing questions with at least one of the tags I marked as interesting.

Comment: Isn't that when the question is tagged with one of your favorited tags ?

Comment: @Eugene please try searching first: [How is the “Interesting” tab populated?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148911/how-is-the-interesting-tab-populated)

Comment: @psubsee2003: aye thanks, haven't used SO or meta's search functionality for long time. (checked google) will do search first next time!

Comment: @Eugene It's ok, searching MSO is very tough because features don't always have the same name as you think they should, but when you ask a question, it gets closed as a dup and you edit to reask a new question and it is also a dup, it's a good sign you aren't doing as much research as you should.